# DataTables Export Buttons Align to Bottom Right

Tags: html, css, datatables

While using DataTables for my project, When i align the Export buttons to the right side of the table using float:right. It is not properly aligned with the right edge of the table. Whereas it is properly aligned when i set float:left.

Please suggest a solution for this.
[image]

```
$(" #adminMainTable,#managerMainTable").DataTable( {
    scrollY:        '50vh',
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging:         false,
    dom: 'frtpB', //This changes the position to Bottom
    buttons: [
        { extend: 'excelHtml5', text: 'To Excel' },
        { extend: 'csvHtml5', text: 'To CSV' },
        { extend: 'pdfHtml5', text: 'To PDF' }
        
    ]
    
});
```

//The below code is for changing the position of buttons to right side of the table

```
$("div#adminMainTable_wrapper,div#managerMainTable_wrapper").find($(".dt-buttons")).css("float","right");
```

Comment: Can you provide the code needed to reproduce this (a [mre])?

Comment: If you have not already done so, you can take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @andrewjames Sorry, I've added the code of what i've changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a similar approach to your code for floating right, you can do this:

```js
$(your selector in here).find($(".dt-buttons button.dt-button:nth-child(3)")).css("margin-right","0");
```

In other words, remove the right-padding from the final button.

Instead of `:nth-child(3)`, you can use `:last-child`. That may be safer if the number of buttons ever changes.

Comment: This solved my issue. Thank you so much AndrewJames : )